# I am encountering two errors while trying to login prestashop admin panel

Tags: authentication, xml-parsing, backend, prestashop-1.7

Error 1: CData section not finished Protect yourself against any dispute with Cus in must_have_module_list.xml file.

Erroe 2: EndTag: '

[image: ScreenShotOfError]

Answer (score 0):

You have some corrupted XML files in **config/xml** directory.

They contains some modules metadata and they are automatically refreshed by Prestashop API on backoffice login, so you can safely delete them.